# How to convert gdoc files to txt files in Google Drive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I loaded a bunch of txt files to my GDrive, to use them in Colab.

They seem to have been converted to gdoc files, which I can't read with Colab.

I am now trying to use the GoogleDrive API to change the MIME type, but the changes simply don't happen:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import requests

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() 
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)


fileList = drive.ListFile({'q': "'1IY_CpY-zjUOLLKeI14MmIB-DYeRcuTAc' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file in fileList:
    print('Title: %s, ID: %s, mimeType: %s' % (file['title'], file['id'], file['mimeType']))
    file['mimeType'] = text/plain
    file.Upload()
    print('Title: %s, ID: %s, mimeType: %s' % (file['title'], file['id'], file['mimeType']))
```

The code seems to work in principle, for if I use it to change the title instead of the mimeType, the title changes.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you are trying to keep the file format in .txt you may just proceed to disable the setting "Convert uploaded files to Google Docs editor format" on the 'Gear' icon > 'Settings' in the Drive UI.

This feature seems to be enabled by default as per https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/11547093

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It ended up doing what you suggested, but it would still be interesting to know how to change a mime type with the GDrive API. It would be more efficient than uploading all the data again